# Can you generate confidence intervals for time series ETS forecast components?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Suppose you fit a time series with the `ets` function from the `forecast` package in `R`:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- ets(USAccDeaths, model="MAM")
summary(fit)

# ETS(M,A,M) 
# 
# Call:
#   ets(y = USAccDeaths, model = "MAM") 
# 
# Smoothing parameters:
#   alpha = 0.4761 
# beta  = 0.0326 
# gamma = 1e-04 
# ...more output...
```

Is it possible to generate confidence intervals for the parameters (e.g. `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`)?  If methods exist, are they restricted to certain taxonomies?  That is, can this method be extended to ARIMA models?